# Python: lists, bins, and sorting

Tags: python, list, mapping, binning

I have a quite specific thing to do and do not know how to accomplish that:
I have two lists, x and y, of corresponding values (about 10k in each list).

First, I need to bin both lists according to their order in x, in bins with N values in each bin. So I cannot pre-define fixed bin edges, I rather need, e.g., 10 values in each bin.

Then I need to compute the median value of the 10 y values corresponding to each x bin.

In the last step, I have a third list, z, with more values like x (about 100k values), and then check for each value, in which x bin it would fall and add the mean value of the corresponding y bin to it (something like: z + mean[y_m:y_n][where x_m < z < x_n])).
Any idea how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can order the data using [*list.sort()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) and then use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to create your bins:

```
s.sort()
bins = []
for i in range(0, len(s), 10):
    bin = s[i: i+10]
    bins.append(bin)
```

To get the median of each bin, average the middle to elements:

```
medians = []
for bin in bins:
    middle = bin[4:6]
    median = sum(middle) / float(len(middle))
    medians.append(median)
```

This should get you started.  I don't want to deprive you of the joy of finishing the program yourself :-)

Comment: or `[ s[i: i+10] for i in range(0, len(s), 10)]`

Comment: @Elazar Yes, a list comprehension would work nicely.  OTOH, beginner questions should typically be answered with the simplest possible tools (i.e. things from the beginning of the Python tutorial rather than techniques that get presented later).

Comment: Thanks, the sorting and slicing is clear (thanks for the nice list comprehension, though). However, I need to sort y by x, which I believe is possible with argsort. The next step, however, is what I'm not sure about. Say, I got bins_x and bins_y by slicing, and med_bins_y is [np.median(bin) for bin in bins_y]. How do I check to what bin of bins_x a value of z belongs, so I can add the corresponding value of med_bins_y to it?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I agree. but nothing bad come out of mentioning the more advanced things in, say, a comment. :)

Comment: @Elazar +1 That was a useful and informative comment.   List comprehensions rock.

Comment: In deed, they do ;) but any ideas on the problem?